# languages required to develop applications for android phones

Tags: android

I am a final year student of engineering(Information tech).

I want to develop an application for android phone, so please tell me which kind of languages are required or which language would be easy and effective. I hope you will help me out.

Answer (score 2):

Programming style of android matches with that of java. If you learn java then you can write code for android with less effort. Also you can get eclise, Netbeans, Intellij ide which suports java and androuid. so I think to learn android please first learn java. Lean android programming from http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/index.html

Comment: I completely agree.  If you want to learn Android, then you should at least start out learning the Java API.

Answer (score 1):

You can develop in a variety of language and framework, however Java should be fine for a start.

Answer (score 0):

This seems kind of basic but you might want to check out the official [Android Developer](http://developer.android.com/index.html) page. It's a great place with a lot of examples on how to use the APIs and a lot of guides on best practices.

Also answering directly to your question, with the official Android SDK you would use Java. That should be fine for almost all applications. Then there is the Android Native Development Kit where you would use C. Those are all available on the page mentioned above. There is also the [Google App Inventor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_App_Inventor), which is a mostly grafical interface for creating applications. Then there is last and least [simple](http://code.google.com/p/simple/) and [basic4Android](http://www.basic4ppc.com/) which use a BASIC dialect.

Anyway, you should probably stick to Java when you first start developing. Most ressources on the internet, like tutorials, help and examples, will be Java. Have fun!